# How to pass message from children Input to parent Chat in react-native-gifted-chat

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I got a chat based on react-native-gifted-chat, with a children InputBox component that has the layout for the input and some buttons plus the Send button.
I'm passing 2 functions to handle onSend and the camera, but I was wondering how to send the text that I'm writing on the InputBox to parent that contains the GiftedChat.

GiftedChat handles an array of messages, but how do I create a new text message based on the input and the button onPress ?

Here's my current code:

### On Parent

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.handleCameraPress = this.handleCameraPress.bind(this);
        this.onSend = this.onSend.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            chatData: {},
            messages: []
        }
    }

onSend(messages = []) {
    alert('sending message');
    this.setState(previousState => ({
        messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
    }))
}

handleCameraPress() {
    alert('camera tapped');
}

renderInputToolbar(props) {
    return ( <InputBox
            {...props}
            messages={ this.messages }
            onSend={ this.onSend }
            handleCameraPress={ this.handleCameraPress }
            containerStyle={ styles.inputToolbarStyle }
        />);
}
```

This is how the GiftedChat looks like:

```
<GiftedChat
     style={{ zIndex: 1 }}
     messages={this.state.messages}
     bottomOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 335 : 0}
     maxComposerHeight={150}
     isAnimated={true}
     user={{ _id: 1 }}
     renderInputToolbar={ this.renderInputToolbar.bind(this) }
/>
```

### On Children

```
render() {
   return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
         <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.6}
            style={styles.cameraButton}
            onPress={ this.props.handleCameraPress }>
            <Icon name='md-camera' style={ styles.cameraIcon } />
            </TouchableOpacity>
              <TextInput
                style={ styles.textInput }
                placeholder={i18n.t('chatInputPlaceholder')}
                returnKeyType={'send'}
                // onChangeText={ message => this.setState({ message })}
                // value={this.props.message}
                blurOnSubmit={false}
                ref={'chatInputRef'}
              />
         <Button
           onPress={ this.props.onSend }
           style={ styles.sendButton}>
           <Icon name='md-send' style={ styles.sendIcon } />
           </Button>
      </View>
   );
}
```

I have to I guess pass a `this.props.message` to `this.props.onSend`? And then merge it to parent's messages?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a state variable , which will be your current Message , and then in Gifted chat , you implement :

```
onInputTextChanged={text => {this.setState({typingMessage: text});}}
```

So now your "this.state.typingMessage" , will always have the value that you are writing in your InputToolbar

If you have a custom render you can access to Input Toolbar value like this with "props.text" :

```
renderSend(props) {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.onSend({
            _id: 10,
            text: props.text,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            user: {
                _id: 1,
                name: 'Mike',
            },
        })}>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```